# Troublesome Frog AIO 2013 Intermediate Python 3.x

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, optimization, time-complexity

Recently I was trying out [this](http://orac.amt.edu.au/cgi-bin/train/problem.pl?problemid=689&set=aio13int) problem and my code got 60% of the marks, with the remaining cases returning TLEs.

> Bazza and Shazza do not like bugs. They wish to clear out all the bugs
>   on their garden fence. They come up with a brilliant idea: they buy
>   some sugar frogs and release them near the fence, letting them eat up
>   all the bugs.
>
> The plan is a great success and the bug infestation is gone. But
>   strangely, they now have a sugar frog infestation. Instead of getting
>   rid of the frogs, Bazza and Shazza decide to set up an obstacle course
>   and watch the frogs jump along it for their enjoyment.
>
> The fence is a series of \$N\$ fence posts of varying heights. Bazza and
>   Shazza will select three fence posts to create the obstacle course,
>   where the middle post is strictly higher than the other two. The frogs
>   are to jump up from the left post to the middle post, then jump down
>   from the middle post to the right post. The three posts do not have to
>   be next to each other as frogs can jump over other fence posts,
>   regardless of the height of those other posts.
>
> The difficulty of an obstacle course is the height of the first jump
>   plus the height of the second jump. The height of a jump is equal to
>   the difference in height between it's two fence posts. Your task is to
>   help Bazza and Shazza find the most difficult obstacle course for the
>   frogs to jump.
>
> **Input**
>   Your program should read from the file. The file will describe
>   a single fence.
>
> The first line of input will contain one integer \$N\$: the number of
>   fence posts. The next \$N\$ lines will each contain one integer \$h_i\$: the
>   height of the ith fence post. You are guaranteed that there will be at
>   least one valid obstacle course: that is, there will be at least one
>   combination of three fence posts where the middle post is strictly
>   higher than the other two.
>
> **Output**
>   Your program should write to the file. Your output file should
>   contain one line with one integer: the greatest difficulty of any
>   possible obstacle course.
>
> **Constraints**
>   To evaluate your solution, the judges will run your
>   program against several different input files. All of these files will
>   adhere to the following bounds:
>
> \$3 \leq N \leq 100,000\$ (the number of fence posts)
>   \$1 \leq h_i \leq 100,000\$ (the height of each post)
>
> As some of the test cases will be quite large,
>   you may need to think about how well your solution scales for larger
>   input values. However, not all the cases will be large. In particular:
>
> For 30% of the marks, \$N \leq 300\$. For an additional 30% of the 
>   marks, \$N \leq 3,000\$. For the remaining 40% of the marks, no special > constraints apply.

Hence, I was wondering if anyone could think of a way to optimize my code (below), or perhaps provide a more elegant, efficient algorithm than the one I am currently using.

Here is my code:

```
infile = open('frogin.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('frogout.txt', 'w')

N = int(infile.readline())

l = []

for i in range(N):
    l.append(int(infile.readline()))

m = 0
#find maximum z-x+z-y such that the middle number z is the largest of x, y, z
for j in range(1, N - 1):
    x = min(l[0: j])
    y = min(l[j + 1:])
    z = l[j]
    if x < z and y < z:
        n = z - x + z - y
        m = n if n > m else m

outfile.write(str(m))

infile.close()
outfile.close()
exit()
```

If you require additional information regarding my solution or the problem, please do comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first let's evaluate your program. I created a test file like

```
from random import randint

n    = 100000
max_ = 100000
with open("frogin.txt", "w") as outf:
    outf.write(str(n) + "\n")
    outf.write("\n".join(str(randint(1, max_)) for _ in range(n)))
```

then ran your code in IPython like

```
%load_ext line_profiler

def test():
    infile = open('frogin.txt', 'r')
    outfile = open('frogout.txt', 'w')
    N = int(infile.readline())
    l = []
    for i in range(N):
        l.append(int(infile.readline()))
    m = 0
    for j in range(1, N - 1):
        pre_l = l[0: j]            # I split these lines
        x = min(pre_l)             # for a bit more detail
        post_l = l[j + 1:]         # on exactly which operations
        y = min(post_l)            # are taking the most time
        z = l[j]
        if x < z and y < z:
            n = z - x + z - y
            m = n if n > m else m
    outfile.write(str(m))
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()

%lprun -f test test()   # instrument the `test` function, then run `test()`
```

which gave

```
Total time: 197.565 s
File: <ipython-input-37-afa35ce6607a>
Function: test at line 1

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           def test():
     2         1          479    479.0      0.0      infile = open('frogin.txt', 'r')
     3         1          984    984.0      0.0      outfile = open('frogout.txt', 'w')
     4         1          195    195.0      0.0      N = int(infile.readline())
     5         1            2      2.0      0.0      l = []
     6    100001       117005      1.2      0.0      for i in range(N):
     7    100000       269917      2.7      0.0          l.append(int(infile.readline()))
     8         1            2      2.0      0.0      m = 0
     9     99999       226984      2.3      0.0      for j in range(1, N - 1):
    10     99998     94137525    941.4     12.2          pre_l = l[0: j]
    11     99998    300309109   3003.2     38.8          x = min(pre_l)
    12     99998     85915575    859.2     11.1          post_l = l[j + 1:]
    13     99998    291183808   2911.9     37.7          y = min(post_l)
    14     99998       441185      4.4      0.1          z = l[j]
    15     99998       212870      2.1      0.0          if x < z and y < z:
    16     99978       284920      2.8      0.0              n = z - x + z - y
    17     99978       181296      1.8      0.0              m = n if n > m else m
    18         1          114    114.0      0.0      outfile.write(str(m))
    19         1          170    170.0      0.0      infile.close()
    20         1          511    511.0      0.0      outfile.close()
```

which shows that 23.3% of your time (46 s) is spent repeatedly slicing your array, and 76.5% (151 s) is spent running `min()` on the slices 200k times.

So - how can we speed this up? Consider

```
a = min(l[0:50001])    # 50000 comparisons
b = min(l[0:50002])    # 50001 comparisons
c = min(a, l[50001])   # 1 comparison
```

Here's the magic: `b` and `c` are **exactly equivalent** but `b` takes something like 10k times longer to run. You have to have `a` calculated first - but you can repeat the same trick, shifted back by 1, to get `a` cheaply, and the same for the `a`'s predecessor, and so on.

In one pass from start to end you can keep a running tally of 'minimum value seen previous to this index'. You can then do the same thing from end to start, keeping a running tally of 'minimum value seen after this index'. You can then zip all three arrays together and find the maximum achievable values.

---

I wrote a quick version,

```
def test():
    ERROR_VAL = 1000000  # too big to be part of any valid solution
    # read input file
    with open("frogin.txt") as inf:
        nums = [int(i) for i in inf.read().split()]
    # check contents
    n = nums.pop(0)
    if len(nums) < n:
        raise ValueError("Input file is too short!")
    elif len(nums) > n:
        raise ValueError("Input file is too long!")
    # min_pre[i] == min(nums[:i])
    min_pre = [0] * n
    min_pre[0] = ERROR_VAL
    for i in range(1, n):
        min_pre[i] = min(nums[i - 1], min_pre[i - 1])
    # min_post[i] == min(nums[i+1:])
    min_post = [0] * n
    min_post[n - 1] = ERROR_VAL
    for i in range(n - 2, -1, -1):
        min_post[i] = min(nums[i + 1], min_post[i + 1])
    return max((nums[i] - min_pre[i]) + (nums[i] - min_post[i]) for i in range(1, n - 1) if min_pre[i] < nums[i] > min_post[i])
```

and profiled it,

```
Total time: 0.300842 s
File: <ipython-input-99-2097216e4420>
Function: test at line 1

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           def test():
     2         1            5      5.0      0.0      ERROR_VAL = 1000000  # too big to be part of any valid solution
     3                                               # read input file
     4         1          503    503.0      0.0      with open("frogin.txt") as inf:
     5         1        99903  99903.0      8.5          nums = [int(i) for i in inf.read().split()]
     6                                               # check contents
     7         1          212    212.0      0.0      n = nums.pop(0)
     8         1            7      7.0      0.0      if len(nums) < n:
     9                                                   raise ValueError("Input file is too short!")
    10         1            2      2.0      0.0      elif len(nums) > n:
    11                                                   raise ValueError("Input file is too long!")
    12                                               # min_pre[i] == min(nums[:i])
    13         1          994    994.0      0.1      min_pre = [0] * n
    14         1            3      3.0      0.0      min_pre[0] = ERROR_VAL
    15    100000       162915      1.6     13.8      for i in range(1, n):
    16     99999       267593      2.7     22.7          min_pre[i] = min(nums[i - 1], min_pre[i - 1])
    17                                               # min_post[i] == min(nums[i+1:])
    18         1         1050   1050.0      0.1      min_post = [0] * n
    19         1            3      3.0      0.0      min_post[n - 1] = ERROR_VAL
    20    100000       167021      1.7     14.2      for i in range(n - 2, -1, -1):
    21     99999       272080      2.7     23.1          min_post[i] = min(nums[i + 1], min_post[i + 1])
    22         1       205222 205222.0     17.4      return max((nums[i] - min_pre[i]) + (nums[i] - min_post[i]) for i in range(1, n - 1) if min_pre[i] < nums[i] > min_post[i])
```

and you can see the run-time for processing 100k values has dropped from 197 s to 0.3 s.